# C#: How do I convert a TimeSpan value to a double?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, double, timespan

How do I convert a `TimeSpan` value to a `double` in C#?

I mean I have this `-08:15:00` and I want a double `-08.15`.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  8 minutes and 15 seconds is *not* equal to 8.15 minutes.

Comment: @KirkWoll: It's not unheard of to represent an angle such as 22°39'46" like 22.3946, so maybe that's what OP wants.

Comment: Everything considered, your question is ambiguous at best. is 8:15:00 h/m/s, or is it m/s/ms? And did you really mean 8:15:00 -> 8.15, or should it be 8:15:00 -> 8.25?

Answer (score 18):

Despite how ambiguous this question is, for future reference, Umar was probably the closest to answering the question, as it was displayed in the title.

To get a `double` from a `TimeSpan` object, you need to pick the most significant measurement, and get the total. As the `Total<x>` property, will return the appropriate full value, and the fractions of that value as a decimal.

So, if you want `8:15:00`, to a `double` - and the `"8"` represents `Hours`, then you'll want `TimeSpan.TotalHours` which will result in a value of 8.25.

If the `"8"` represents `Minutes`, then again, you'll use the appropriate property `TimeSpan.TotalMinutes` for the same result, and so on.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reference, I wonder if OP was downvoted because of the wrong conversion from -08:15:00 to -08.15 instead of -08.25, the question itself is legit in itself. If you are making a system that is to be used by book keepers to manage salary based on how much you've worked you'll need something like this.

Answer (score 11):

You could use `TimeSpan.TotalMinutes` (gets the value of the current `TimeSpan` structure expressed in whole and fractional minutes) or other similar [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/02c79d34.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Do not repeat this at home!

```
double value = (timeSpan.Hours + timeSpan.Minutes / 100.0 + timeSpan.Seconds / 10000.0) * (timeSpan > TimeSpan.Zero ? 1 : -1);
```

Comment: This won't be accurate because it will ignore Days, Hours and Milliseconds.

Comment: @UmarFarooqKhawaja Not `Hours`, actually

Comment: Indeed, @VMAtm!

Comment: how about: `(timeSpan.Hours + timeSpan.Minutes / 60.0 + timeSpan.Seconds / 3600.0) * (timeSpan > TimeSpan.Zero ? 1 : -1);`

Answer (score 0):

In the case of operations with `DateTime` in its `double` format obtained with `.ToOADate()`, `TimeSpan` must be converted to `double` directly with `.TotalDays` since the unit (1.0) for `DateTime` is a day.

With a functional mindset:

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static double ToDouble(this TimeSpan o) => o.TotalDays;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use string.format, then parse it like this:

```
   double.Parse(string.Format("-HH.mm"))
```